How to use Group Policy to update existing predefined firewall rules?
I am trying to harden my server environment by disabling firewall rules that are not needed.  I don't want to delete the unneeded rules and I don't want to create block rules, just disable the ones I don't want enabled.  This is regardless of whether or not there's an actual listener for the related port.  It's more of a compliance issue rather than a security issue - the firewall rule must not be enabled.
I am trying to do it through GPO, however I consistently keep getting my rules doubled - one local set and one set from Group Policy.  Because of the nature of Windows Firewall, unless there is a block rule (which there won't be in my case), if even one rule exists that permits the traffic, then it's permitted.  Here is an example workflow:
Setup:  Servers have two enabled rules in the "AllJoyn Router" group.  Since we are not using this and there's no listener, there's no reason for the rules to be enabled.

Ensure Policy is linked to correct OU and server exists directly in that OU (no sub-OUs)
Ensure no other Policies are applied to the OU, either directly or by inheritance.
Configure all three Profiles as follows:

Firewall state = On
Inbound connections = Block
Outbound connections = Allow
Display a notification = Yes
Allow unicast response = Yes
Apply local firewall rules = Yes (Or "No".  This doesn't seem to make a difference.)
Apply local connection security rules = Yes


Add new "Inbound" rule to Policy using a Rule Type of Predefined = "AllJoyn Router"
Leave the checkboxes checked
Allow the connection
Select all the rules, right-click and select "Disable Rule"
Force Group Policy update on server
Examine "Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security" console and see that there now four "AllJoyn Router" rules, two enabled (as was originally) and two disabled.

It was my understanding that "Apply local firewall rules = Yes" is supposed to merge the rules, overriding local rules with the Group Policy version.  However, that is not happening.  No matter whether "Apply local firewall rules" is "Yes" or "No" I always get my rules doubled.
Either I'm missing something or not understanding something.  I expect there to be only one of each rule, and each rule should reflect it's configuration in Group Policy.
